# DataIndex property for extjs textfield in compositefield

Tags: extjs

Iam design one formpanel with set of controls
in this form panel design textfields like

```
{
    xtype: 'compositefield',
    fieldLabel: 'City',
    labelAlign: 'left',
    id: 'AddEditPeopleCompositeFieldCity',
    items: [ /* * txtCity * */ ,
    {
        xtype: 'spacer',
        width: 10
    }, {
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        value: 'State:',
        style: 'padding-top:3px;',
        align: 'bottom'
    }, /* * txtState * */ ,
    {
        xtype: 'spacer',
        width: 5
    }, {
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        value: 'Zip:',
        style: 'padding-top:3px;',
        align: 'bottom'
    }, /* * txtZip * */ ]
}
```

but for this textfields "dataIndex" property not working

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no `dataIndex` property for compositefields. You need to set `name` property for each fields. You can use the `getValues()` method available for the form object to get the values.

For details and code example, refer to the Ext JS example that come with the library download.

---

To load data onto the form you can use the `load()` or `loadRecord()` method available with the form. Have a look at [this example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/examples/form/composite-field.js) code. Go through the code for button handlers for the form. There is example of both retrieving and set data to composite fields.

Comment: iam retrive data from database   ,So how to set those values to textfields

Comment: refer to the updated answer and also go thru the example code.